# Express installation issue

Tags: express

**I am new to nodeJS and I am trying to install express as a dependency but it gives me error as follows::**

```
C:\wamp\www\ExpressJS\node>npm install express --save
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install express as a dependency of itself
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\wamp\www\ExpressJS\node\npm-debug.log

**any help would be much appericiated, This is my npm-debug file**
```

Answer (score 7):

well I know what is the exact problem with you and that is, while creating the project by

**npm init**

you have given the name as the dependency name.

So change Name of your project by going into **package.json** and give a different name. 
And then install again by the same command
like

**npm install --save**

and I can say that you will not get the same error again

Answer (score 1):

while npm init do not give app name as 'express'

Answer (score 0):

You're running `npm i express --save` being located inside `ExpressJS` folder. Please go outside and install `express` there.

Answer (score 0):

When start a node project,  you need to use command `npm init` in target folder. Then install express module.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder name and the package.json `name` key is the same as the module name like this

**terminal**:

```
npm install express
```

**json** file:

```
// express/package.json

{
  "name": "express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

... < Error >.

To solve that:

**json** file:

```
// <foldername>/package.json

{
  "name": "newName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Then

**terminal**:

```
npm install express
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different name from express while initializing npm i.e while doing **npm init**

In your package.json check key **name**

> "name": "express"

replace express to some other name then your error will be resolved.